# What to await when using open file dialog asynchronously?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

So, I'm working on some demo code for a future project and the easiest way for me to do that is to use the open file dialog with a console. The problem is, I constantly get these errors:

> ContextSwitchDeadlock was detected Message: The CLR has been unable to
>   transition from COM context 0x134bfd8 to COM context 0x134c090 for 60
>   seconds.  The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is
>   most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing  a very long
>   running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation
>   generally has a negative performance  impact and may even lead to the
>   application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating
>   continually over time.  To avoid this problem, all single threaded
>   apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives  (such as
>   CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long
>   running operations.

So the obvious answer is that I need the operations to be taking place on a different thread.

So I went from using this:

```
FileParserOne parser = new FileParserOne();
Thread thread = new Thread(parser.GetFile);
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

to this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(parser.GetFile);
```

Problem now being that the project ends as soon as it starts, fires off that task because it's not awaiting anything. Why? Because I'm not sure what it is I should be awaiting within the get file method which opens the text file and separates the words.

```
internal async void GetFile()
        {
            Stream stream = null;
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((stream = dialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        using (stream)
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                            {
                                String temp = reader.ReadToEnd();
                                m_WordArray = temp.Replace
                                    ("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", " ")
                                .Replace("\"", string.Empty).Split(' ').ToArray<string>();
                                Console.Read();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just asking the obvious since it is not used in your question: have you used the `await` keyword before `Task.Factory.StartNew`?

Comment: Also I'd make two little adjustments. Instead of `void` let the method return type be a `Task` which is the TAP equivalent to void. And secondly add a `ConfigureAwait(false)` after the starting of the task since you want to assure that it is handled on a threadpool thread.

Comment: Please don't do `catch (Exception e)` - it's such a terrible anti-pattern that leads to buggy and hard to maintain code.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I'll be sure to optimize all code posted in crowd..?

Comment: @Eidenai - Optimize? No, I'm suggesting that if you do that in your code at any time then you are doing the wrong thing. You shouldn't need to "optimize" - you just shouldn't write it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is exiting immediately because the calling thread won't wait unless you tell it to do so, as shown in this example:

```
Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(parser.GetFile);
myTask.Wait(); // wait for myTask to complete
```

Comment: Wow. That's embarrassing.